# C++ template method

Tags: c++, string, templates, methods

I've written a simplified version of the STL basic_string class :

```
template<typename chrT>
class strT
{
protected:

    chrT * m_pcBuf;

    size_t m_nLen;

public:

    strT( void );

    strT( const chrT * pcStr );

    strT( const strT<chrT> & rsStr );

    virtual ~strT( void );

    virtual inline size_t len( void ) const;

    virtual int cmp( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual inline const chrT & operator [] ( size_t nPos ) const;

    virtual inline chrT & operator [] ( size_t nPos );

    virtual bool & operator == ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual bool & operator != ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual bool & operator < ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual bool & operator > ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual bool & operator <= ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual bool & operator >= ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr ) const;

    virtual inline strT<chrT> & operator = ( const strT<chrT> & rsStr );

    virtual inline operator chrT * ( void );

protected:

    void _alloc( size_t nLen );

    void _realloc( size_t nLen );

public:

    static const size_t none;
};

template<typename inchr, typename outchr>
strT<outchr> convert( const strT<inchr> & rsIn );

typedef strT<char> str;
typedef strT<wchar_t> wstr;
```

Currently, if i want to convert between, say, char and wchar_t, i can simply do :

```
int main( void )
{
    str as = "foo";
    wstr ws = convert<char, wchar_t>( as );
}
```

But instead of this functionnal approach i would like to have a template method allowing to do such conversions. This is very likely false, but here is what i'd like to do :

```
template<typename chrT>
class strT
{
    // ...

public:

    template<typename outchr>
    virtual strT<outchr> convert( void ) const;

    // ...
}

template<typename chrT, typename outchr>
strT<outchr> strT<chrT>::convert<outchr>( void ) const
{
    // ...
}
```

And then :

```
int main( void )
{
    str as = "foo";
    wstr ws = as.convert<wchar_t>();
}
```

Is it possible please ?

Thanks for your help !

PS : Forgot to mention that i don't want to use C++11 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost possible - you can have a member function template, but it cannot be `virtual`. So if that's fine with you, drop `virtual` from the declaration and you're set.

To see why member function templates can't be `virtual`, think about the most common implementation of virtual member functions - the virtual function table. That's a table of pointers to functions, storing one pointer for each virtual function. How many pointers would need to be stored for a virtual member function template? One for `convert<char>`, one for `convert<wchar_t>`, one for `convert<int>`, one for `convert<int*>`, one for `convert<int**>`, one for `convert<std::vector<int> >`, one for ...

The problem is that *arbitrarily many* functions can be instantiated from the template. There's no way to do dynamic dispatch for them. (Note that a similar problem appears in all other dynamic dispatch implementations as well - a template is just potentially infinitely many functions)

Comment: Thanks, that's what the compiler tells me. Why isn't it possible ? I don't get the relationship between genericity and virtual here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a templated constructor?

```
template<typename chrT>
class strT
{
public:
    template<typename otherT>
    strT(otherT* o) { ... }
}
```

To implement the conversion, you can specialize the constructor for the different possibilities of `chrT` and `otherT`

Comment: Thanks but this would determine the conversion output type at object construction and would only allow a single target type per instance, which is not exatly what i'm looking for. Thanks for your answer anyway !